# Is it correct to add Experiment as a grouping factor in LMM?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model

I have a study with 2 within-participant predictors with two levels each, and one between-participants with also two levels (group). The two groups perform the same task, but with different stimuli (neutral words vs. color words), so in my first analysis I have created a LMM with participant as the grouping variable for the random effects. One year later, I conducted a second experiment to replicate the findings, and analyzed the data with the same model structure. However, I would like to merge the data from the two experiments to have a larger sample size, and I thought it might be useful to add Experiment as grouping factor on random effects. I don't know it that is correct, because I already added participant, and participants are different on both experiments, so maybe Experiment random effects are explained on participants random effects?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since the sets of individuals are different in the two experiments, you don’t have repeated measurements, thus you can’t fit random effects here.